# Value Error When Infilling Datetime Index

Tags: pandas, numpy, datetime

I'm trying to infill the dates on a dataframe with a DateTimeIndex. Here's the setup to get the initial dataframe:

```
days =  (date(2018,8,5),date(2018,8,6),date(2018,8,9))
colors = ('red','red','blue')
tuples = list(zip(days,colors))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples,names=['day','color'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2) \
              ,index=index,columns=['first','second'])
```

which produces this dataframe:

```
                  first      second
   day     color        
2018-08-05  red   0.044029   1.135556
2018-08-06  red   0.212579  -0.157853
2018-08-09  blue -0.502317  -0.019823
```

Now to reindex to fill in missing dates:

```
start = df.index.get_level_values('day').min()
end = df.index.get_level_values('day').max()
reindexer = pd.date_range(start,end)
df2 = df.groupby('color').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(reindexer))
```

which produces this error:

```
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer
```

Online there are several posts describing this message as due to datetime64 arrays not supporting buffering, and some hints as to hacks to work around. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug? What's the recommended workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) by second level for DatetimeIndex and then working your solution:

```
df2 = (df.reset_index(level=1)
         .groupby('color')['first','second']
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(reindexer)))
print (df2)
                     first    second
color                               
blue  2018-08-05       NaN       NaN
      2018-08-06       NaN       NaN
      2018-08-07       NaN       NaN
      2018-08-08       NaN       NaN
      2018-08-09 -0.917287 -1.115499
red   2018-08-05  0.182462  0.205502
      2018-08-06  0.541304 -1.525548
      2018-08-07       NaN       NaN
      2018-08-08       NaN       NaN
      2018-08-09       NaN       NaN
```

Or:

```
start = df.index.get_level_values('day').min()
end = df.index.get_level_values('day').max()
colors = df.index.get_level_values('color').unique()
dates = pd.date_range(start,end)

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, colors], names=['day','color'])

df = df.reindex(mux)
print (df)
                     first    second
day        color                    
2018-08-05 red   -0.181284  0.162945
           blue        NaN       NaN
2018-08-06 red    0.920916  0.691335
           blue        NaN       NaN
2018-08-07 red         NaN       NaN
           blue        NaN       NaN
2018-08-08 red         NaN       NaN
           blue        NaN       NaN
2018-08-09 red         NaN       NaN
           blue   1.286144 -2.356252
```

Comment: Thanks! The first solution works great and is just what I needed. But is it surprising that this should be necessary? Why needed to convert to a column before grouping, instead of just grouping on an index level?